# mysql sum values from query

Tags: mysql

The mysql query looks like:

```
SELECT count(f.id) as total, m1.fname FROM members m1 INNER JOIN new f ON m1.id = f.id
```

The result of that query:

```
   total | fname  | 
  ------------------
    2    |  john
    3    |  mike
    5    |  july
```

How can I sum values from column "total" using this mysql query?

Comment: Just curious, but why are you summing ID's?

Comment: I want to sum values from column "total", not the values of ID's

Comment: Just an observation : using ids for semantic meaning of your model it could not be the best idea to model things. Id should be only used for persistence of models

Answer (score 2):

Use `SUM` on the subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(c.total) AS total_sum
FROM (
    SELECT count(f.id) as total, m1.fname
    FROM
        members m1 INNER JOIN
        new f ON m1.id = f.id
) AS c
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use sum() instead of count(). did you check sum?

```
SELECT sum(f.id) as total, m1.fname FROM members m1 INNER JOIN new f ON m1.id = f.id
```

Comment: in that case I get sum od "id" values, not values from "total" column

Comment: sorry I understand you want to sum ids.